# AttributeError: 'MainHandler' object has no attribute '_render_template'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I have a question on Google App Engine (python). I can not find the problem, but it somehow does not work as expected. Error message is

```
self.response.out.write(self._render_template('main.html',template_context))
AttributeError: 'MainHandler' object has no attribute '_render_template'
```

My code is below.What is the problem?

```
import webapp2
import os
import jinja2

from google.appengine.api import users
from models import Note

jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user is not None:
        logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        template_context = {
            'user':user.nickname(),
            'logout_url':logout_url,
        }
        def _render_template(self,template_name, context=None):
            if context is None:
                context = {}
            template = jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
            return template.rendet(context)
        self.response.out.write(self._render_template('main.html',template_context))

    else:
        login_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
        self.redirect(login_url)
def post(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user is None:
        self.error(401)
    note = Note(parent=ndb.Key("User",user.nickname()),title=self.request.get('title'),content=self.request.get('content'))
    note.put()
    logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
    template_context = {
        'user': user.nickname(),
        'logout_url':logout_url,
    }
    template = jinja_env.get_template('main.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_context))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

### Below is my yaml files.

```
application: MYAPPLICATION
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
```

### version: latest

Comment: add this BaseHandler: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html#webapp2_extras.jinja2.Jinja2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the `_render_template` method inside an if statement in your `get` method.

Don't do that; define it at the same level as `get` and `post`.

Also, fix the last line: `return template.render(...)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it!